# Node.js export both router and function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm exporting router at the end of the file and also exporting a function, but I can only get one of them to work at a time.

```
// weather.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

refreshWeather(){
// Refresh weather...
}

exports = router; // It's either this
exports.refresh = function() { // or this.
    refreshWeather();
    console.log('Done refreshing');
};
```

from my main app.js I want to be able to do both:

```
//app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var weather = require('./routes/weather.js');

app.use(weather) // I want to be able to use this for routing
weather.refresh(); // But also be able to call refresh function of weather.js
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Any reason why you can't just do this?  This seems cleaner than defining a function within exports and trying to call another function within weather.js.

```
module.exports = { 
  router:router,
  refreshWeather:refreshWeather
}
```

Then in app.js

```
var weather = require('./routes/weather.js');
app.use(weather.router)
weather.refreshWeather()
```

If you don't want to do it that way, try changing exports = router to exports.router = router.  Then within app.js you can call weather.router.

Comment: I tried this but I get the following error:

`TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object`

Comment: Re-read the answer. Its easy to miss. You have to use the router property from the export now `app.use(weather.router)`